# Problem in cooccur package: cooccur function produces NaNs

Tags: r

I want to work with the cooccur package.
But when i use the cooccur function it produces NaNs.
The data:

```
> df <- data.frame(species = c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"), 
+                  site1 = c(0,0,21,1,68,4,80,144,25,13),
+                  site2 = c(0,1,35,4,80,12,52,203,38,10),
+                  site3 = c(0,0,26,8,63,24,122,178,53,0),
+                  site4 = c(4,8,22,0,22,1,89,375,14,9))
> rownames(df) <- df$species
> df <- df[,-1]
> df
  site1 site2 site3 site4
a     0     0     0     4
b     0     1     0     8
c    21    35    26    22
d     1     4     8     0
e    68    80    63    22
f     4    12    24     1
g    80    52   122    89
h   144   203   178   375
i    25    38    53    14
j    13    10     0     9
```

When I try to run the cooccur function i recieve these warnings:

```
> co <- cooccur(mat = df, type = "spp_site", spp_names = TRUE)
  |================================================================================================================================| 100%
There were 45 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> warnings()
Advarselsbeskeder:
1: In phyper(0:min_inc, min_inc, nsite - min_inc, max_inc) : NaNs produced
2: In phyper(0:min_inc, min_inc, nsite - min_inc, max_inc) : NaNs produced
3: In phyper(0:min_inc, min_inc, nsite - min_inc, max_inc) : NaNs produced
4: In phyper(0:min_inc, min_inc, nsite - min_inc, max_inc) : NaNs produced
5: In phyper(0:min_inc, min_inc, nsite - min_inc, max_inc) : NaNs produced
6: In phyper(0:min_inc, min_inc, nsite - min_inc, max_inc) : NaNs produced
7: In phyper(0:min_inc, min_inc, nsite - min_inc, max_inc) : NaNs produced
8: In phyper(0:min_inc, min_inc, nsite - min_inc, max_inc) : NaNs produced
```

and when I try to plot the data I get this error

```
> plot(co)
Error in ans[ypos] <- rep(yes, length.out = len)[ypos] : 
  replacement has length zero
In addition: Warning message:
In rep(yes, length.out = len) : 'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL
```

Any help on how to solve this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your data should have 0's and 1's representing the absences and. presences of your data. I would highly recommend you check this [site](https://griffithdan.github.io/pages/code_and_data/cooccur.html). Here is a reproducible example using the data from the link:

```r
library(cooccur)
data(finches)
finches
#>                          Seymour Baltra Isabella Fernandina Santiago Rabida
#> Geospiza magnirostris          0      0        1          1        1      1
#> Geospiza fortis                1      1        1          1        1      1
#> Geospiza fuliginosa            1      1        1          1        1      1
#> Geospiza difficilis            0      0        1          1        1      0
#> Geospiza scandens              1      1        1          0        1      1
#> Geospiza conirostris           0      0        0          0        0      0
#> Camarhynchus psittacula        0      0        1          1        1      1
#> Camarhynchus pauper            0      0        0          0        0      0
#> Camarhynchus parvulus          0      0        1          1        1      1
#> Platyspiza crassirostris       0      0        1          1        1      1
#> Cactospiza pallida             0      0        1          1        1      0
#> Cactospiza heliobates          0      0        1          1        0      0
#> Certhidea olivacea             1      1        1          1        1      1
#>                          Pinzon Santa.Cruz Santa.Fe San.Cristobal Espanola
#> Geospiza magnirostris         1          1        1             1        0
#> Geospiza fortis               1          1        1             1        0
#> Geospiza fuliginosa           1          1        1             1        1
#> Geospiza difficilis           0          1        0             1        0
#> Geospiza scandens             1          1        1             1        0
#> Geospiza conirostris          0          0        0             0        1
#> Camarhynchus psittacula       1          1        1             0        0
#> Camarhynchus pauper           0          0        0             0        0
#> Camarhynchus parvulus         1          1        1             1        0
#> Platyspiza crassirostris      1          1        1             1        0
#> Cactospiza pallida            1          1        0             1        0
#> Cactospiza heliobates         0          0        0             0        0
#> Certhidea olivacea            1          1        1             1        1
#>                          Floreana Genovesa Marchena Pinta Darwin Wolf
#> Geospiza magnirostris           1        1        1     1      1    1
#> Geospiza fortis                 1        0        1     1      0    0
#> Geospiza fuliginosa             1        0        1     1      0    0
#> Geospiza difficilis             1        1        0     1      1    1
#> Geospiza scandens               1        0        1     1      0    0
#> Geospiza conirostris            0        1        0     0      0    0
#> Camarhynchus psittacula         1        0        1     1      0    0
#> Camarhynchus pauper             1        0        0     0      0    0
#> Camarhynchus parvulus           1        0        0     1      0    0
#> Platyspiza crassirostris        1        0        1     1      0    0
#> Cactospiza pallida              0        0        0     0      0    0
#> Cactospiza heliobates           0        0        0     0      0    0
#> Certhidea olivacea              1        1        1     1      1    1
cooccur.finches <- cooccur(finches,
                           type = "spp_site",
                           thresh = TRUE,
                           spp_names = TRUE)
#>   |                                                                              |                                                                      |   0%  |                                                                              |=                                                                     |   1%  |                                                                              |==                                                                    |   2%  |                                                                              |==                                                                    |   3%  |                                                                              |===                                                                   |   4%  |                                                                              |====                                                                  |   5%  |                                                                              |=====                                                                 |   7%  |                                                                              |=====                                                                 |   8%  |                                                                              |======                                                                |   9%  |                                                                              |=======                                                               |  10%  |                                                                              |========                                                              |  11%  |                                                                              |========                                                              |  12%  |                                                                              |=========                                                             |  13%  |                                                                              |==========                                                            |  14%  |                                                                              |                                                                      |   0%  |                                                                              |=============                                                         |  18%  |                                                                              |==============                                                        |  19%  |                                                                              |===============                                                       |  21%  |                                                                              |===============                                                       |  22%  |                                                                              |================                                                      |  23%  |                                                                              |=================                                                     |  25%  |                                                                              |==================                                                    |  26%  |                                                                              |===================                                                   |  27%  |                                                                              |====================                                                  |  29%  |                                                                              |=====================                                                 |  30%  |                                                                              |======================                                                |  31%  |                                                                              |=======================                                               |  32%  |                                                                              |========================                                              |  34%  |                                                                              |=========================                                             |  35%  |                                                                              |=========================                                             |  36%  |                                                                              |==========================                                            |  38%  |                                                                              |===========================                                           |  39%  |                                                                              |============================                                          |  40%  |                                                                              |=============================                                         |  42%  |                                                                              |==============================                                        |  43%  |                                                                              |===============================                                       |  44%  |                                                                              |================================                                      |  45%  |                                                                              |=================================                                     |  47%  |                                                                              |==================================                                    |  48%  |                                                                              |===================================                                   |  49%  |                                                                              |===================================                                   |  51%  |                                                                              |====================================                                  |  52%  |                                                                              |=====================================                                 |  53%  |                                                                              |======================================                                |  55%  |                                                                              |=======================================                               |  56%  |                                                                              |========================================                              |  57%  |                                                                              |=========================================                             |  58%  |                                                                              |==========================================                            |  60%  |                                                                              |===========================================                           |  61%  |                                                                              |============================================                          |  62%  |                                                                              |=============================================                         |  64%  |                                                                              |=============================================                         |  65%  |                                                                              |==============================================                        |  66%  |                                                                              |===============================================                       |  68%  |                                                                              |================================================                      |  69%  |                                                                              |=================================================                     |  70%  |                                                                              |==================================================                    |  71%  |                                                                              |===================================================                   |  73%  |                                                                              |====================================================                  |  74%  |                                                                              |=====================================================                 |  75%  |                                                                              |======================================================                |  77%  |                                                                              |=======================================================               |  78%  |                                                                              |=======================================================               |  79%  |                                                                              |========================================================              |  81%  |                                                                              |=========================================================             |  82%  |                                                                              |==========================================================            |  83%  |                                                                              |===========================================================           |  84%  |                                                                              |============================================================          |  86%  |                                                                              |=============================================================         |  87%  |                                                                              |==============================================================        |  88%  |                                                                              |===============================================================       |  90%  |                                                                              |================================================================      |  91%  |                                                                              |=================================================================     |  92%  |                                                                              |=================================================================     |  94%  |                                                                              |==================================================================    |  95%  |                                                                              |===================================================================   |  96%  |                                                                              |====================================================================  |  97%  |                                                                              |===================================================================== |  99%  |                                                                              |======================================================================| 100%

plot(cooccur.finches)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you Quinten! Transforming to 0's and 1's solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you caught this already, but your code uses `type="spp_site"` when your example data is formatted as "site_spp". This makes a difference in your output, including the figure, so it should be obvious. Just in case though, you can use `co <- cooccur(mat = t(df), type = "spp_site", spp_names = TRUE)`. The package documentation indicates that you can use `type = site_spp` but this doesn't work!